# Where to begin for filtering user's inputs to give result

Tags: html, css, database, filter

I'm creating a website to be able to find the best result after a user has added their input. I'm newer to programming with only a few months in HTML/CSS and very light Javascript. Due to this, I am unable to properly word my question due to the lack of education so far, thus why I'm seeking advice here!

Best way to describe my idea is by an example:

1. User is looking for a dish recommendation to cook.
2. User inputs data (what they are craving, allergies, their cooking experience level, etc..)
3. Database filters through user's inputs to find the best result, giving them the dish they should cook.
4. Result is displayed on page for user to see.

If this is a hard to follow idea, let me know what the issue is and I will try to elaborate. I'm just unsure as to where to begin with this, what code-language to use, and how to go about to make my idea a reality.

Thank you in advance for any help/criticism sent my way!

Comment: teh idea is easy. but i still dpn't get what you are asking for.why do you don't start with an tutorial for mysql like this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/

Comment: I'm just looking as to where to begin and how to execute the idea. Thanks for the link! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead with following steps:

- Create mock up/ have an idea of how the screen will look.
- Try to create that lay out in html css, css frameworks such as bootstrap can help you to quickly build that user interface.
- Create some dummy data JSON and pull the data form that and make app working with Dummy data.
- As you know JavaScript you can write backend code in node.js, identify the db you want to work on.
- create a table structure / Schema for you data, as per database of your choice, you can  use any freeware here, like mongodb, mysql etc.
- Once this is done try to connect db with backend code of node.js
- Code service/API in node to send data to front end view to display.